# What concurrency issues can this PostgreSQL code create?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions, isolation, repeatable-read

Ok so here's the schema, which is pretty self-explanatory:

```
STORE(storeID, name, city)
PRODUCT(productID, name, brand)
PRODUCT_FOR_SALE(productID, storeID, price)
```

I have 2 transactions: **T1 and T2**.
`T1` raises by 5% the price for any product sold in any store in 'London'.
`T2` lowers by 10% the price for any product whose cost is >= $1050

What I am asked is to tell what kind of **concurrency anomaly** they may result in, and what **isolation level** I should apply to which transaction to make it safe.

The code for the transactions is not given, but I suppose it would be something on the lines of:

```
# T1:
BEGIN;
    UPDATE product_for_sale 
    SET    price = price + ((price/100) *5)
    WHERE  storeID IN (SELECT storeID FROM store WHERE city='London')
COMMIT;

# T2:
BEGIN;
    UPDATE product_for_sale
    SET    price = price - (price/10)
    WHERE  price >= 1050
COMMIT;
```

My "guess" to what might happen with `READ COMMITTED` (default) is:
Considering a product P, sold in 'London' for $1049

- both transactions begin

  they both consider their row sets: T1 will consider all products sold in London (which includes P), T2 will consider products whose price is $1050 or more (which excludes P)

  T1 commits and sets the price of P to $1101 but, since P wasn't in T2's row set to begin with, the change goes unnoticed, and T2 commits without considering it

Which, if I'm not messing up definitions, should be a case of phantom read, which would be fixed if I set T2 to `ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is not quite clear what you mean with a concurrency issue. It could be:

1. something that could conceivably be a problem, but is handled by PostgreSQL automatically so that no problems arise.
2. something that can generate an unexpected error or an undesirable result.

For 1., this is handled by locks that serialize transactions that are trying to modify the same rows concurrently.

I assume you are more interested in 2.

What you describe can happen, but it is not a concurrency problem. It just means that T1 *logically* takes place before T2. This will work just fine on all isolation levels.

I might be missing something, but the only potential problem I see here is a deadlock between the two statements:

They both can update several rows, so it could happen that one of them updates row X first and then tries to update row Y, which has already been updated by the other statement. The first statement then is blocked. Now the second statement wants to update row Y and is blocked too.

Such a deadlock is broken by the deadlock resolver after one second by killing off one of the statements with an error.

Note that deadlocks are not real problems either, all your code has to do is to repeat the failed transaction.

Comment: By concurrency issue I mean either dirty read, unrepeatable read, phantom read or a serialization anomaly. In general, anything that would cause the commands to yield unexpected results

This question has been presented in several exams in the past from my professor, and I just can't get my head around it. 

I guess he expects some answer like "this could happen with READ COMMITTED, setting this transaction to this isolation level would fix that", but I couldn't find any better explanation than the one in the body of the question, which is similar to an example provided in the postgres doc

Comment: In PostgreSQL, these two statements cannot cause a serialization anomaly to happen, regardless of the serialization level. If you consider deadlocks a serialization anomaly, then that's the one that can happen.